# Playframework Java - How to receive chunked HTTP request in controller

Tags: playframework, akka-stream

I have a play controller in java. The request is of 15MB in size. This request is coming from APIGEE in a streamed manner. I have used raw body parser in the controller to write the data into the file. But I think it writes the whole request data into a file at once. Which means the whole request must be in memory at one point to a time before it gets written to a file. Is there any way to receive stream request in play framework (JAVA)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The raw body parser does not buffer the whole body into memory, it buffers the body up to a point (configured using `play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer`, defaults to 100kb), and once that is exceeded, it flushes the body to a file and starts writing it to the file, but it also has a limit on how much data it will write to a file, which is configured using `play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer`, and this defaults to 10mb. Your 15mb body is probably exceeding that limit, so you need to increase `play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer` accordingly. This is all explained in [the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaBodyParsers#Content-length-limits).

To answer your actual question on how to stream requests, documentation for writing custom body parsers in Java is here:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaBodyParsers#Writing-a-custom-body-parser

That explains most things you need to know about how Play body parsers work and therefore how to do streaming body parsing, no point in duplicating that documentation in this answer.

Comment: Hi @James Roper - I hope you will still check back on this - so if I have the following in my `application.conf`: `play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer=128k play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer=1G` and my file is about 15MB, does that mean `BodyParser.Raw` will read about 128k from my file, and write that to disk, and then continue with the next 128k until it is done with the 15MB file? i.e., we used only 128k memory to upload a 15MB file? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's a bit different to that. The way it works is that it reads up to 128K, once that's exceeded, it writes that 128K to disk, and then continues to write all subsequent bytes directly to disk, it doesn't buffer them in memory at all. That said, there are other IO related memory buffers involved prior to the Raw parser getting involved, so it's likely that more than 128K memory might be used. Configuration options for all the akka-http buffers can be found here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/configuration.html

Comment: thank you @Jame Roper! this is very helpful information